# Pourquoi « faire de la bourgeoisie une classe » et pas « faire la bourgeoisie une classe » ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, littérature, compléments

[Extrait](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/victor-hugo-on-a-voulu-a-tort-faire-de-la-bourgeoisie-une-classe) tiré de *Les Misérables* de Victor Hugo :

> On a voulu, à tort, faire de la bourgeoisie une classe.

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi l'auteur écrit **faire de la bourgeoisie** et pas **faire la bourgeoisie** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le de est parce que l'objet direct de *faire* est ici *classe*, et non pas *bourgeoisie* ([sens III. D.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/faire)).

Le *de* est de fait l’abréviation de *à partir de*, et l'expression d'origine *faire un X à partir de Y*, même si la formule considérée aujourd'hui comme correcte ou plus élégante est *faire de Y un X*.